# Does the linearregression() handle the dummy Variable trap?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

As the title says, Does the `linearregression()` handle the dummy Variable trap by itself ? or do I need to program its solution implicitly? Also, does the dummy variable trap occurs with all datasets that include dummy variables ( for sure after encoding the categorical data in the dataset) or just in specific scenarios?

Comment: do you mean 'dummy Variable **trick**' or 'dummy Variable **trap**'? If latter, what trap are you referring to?

Comment: @lpounng its dummy Variable trap found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ml-dummy-variable-trap-in-regression-models/

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using sklearn's LinearRegression.

The answer is no:

The idea behind the dummy trap is if one column has labels [1,2 or 3], Then you only need two columns to represent the information as [0,0] , [0,1] or [1,0]. So yes it applies to all **feature** columns which get one-hot encoded.

This is not true if the **target** column was multi-label as dropping a label here would means a low prediction probability in one class would mean a high prediction of the another class but would completely ignore prediction of the third.

If you are creating the one-hot encoding on the **features** you will have to manually delete one for each multi-label column you had.

Easier yet is the [get_dummies method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) (with drop_first = True)